# Bounds of result value

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

I want to bound the result value of division:

for example:

$$ \frac{x}{y}=z $$
$$ z>=1: 1, z<1: z $$

if z>=1 then z = 1

if z<1 then  z = z

Can in be done using math operations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that $z = \min(1, \frac{x}{y})$ in this case